# Is there a better way to read data?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making an Android application that displays information about countries. For each country I have defined ~10 parameters.

For the moment I store information about each country in an separate xml file in the res/values/country.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="countryX">
        <!-- Country Name -->
        <item>Name</item>
        <!-- Continent -->
        <item>Continent</item>
        ...
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

When I populate the class storing my country objects, I read the information from each array with a code similar to the one below.

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] countryInfo = res.getStringArray(R.array.countryX);
```

countryInfo is passed to the class constructor where I store in my class fields the values from the String array based on the predefined layout from the xml file. In constructor I check that the size of the countryInfo is at least the size of the parameters I want to fill(in this case 10). If the size is smaller, I fill the fields of the class with default values.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

I'm new to Android development and this method I came up based on what I studied so far and research done on web.

Comment: What about using a **database**? It seems to me being more fit for this use case.

Comment: I don't have experience with databases yet in Android so maybe the next question is a dumb question: From where do I populate the database?

Comment: Probably, you would like to use database if there is such use case. Are you planning to change/add country information later?

Comment: I plan to add/change country information but not from inside the app. This data is static and any add/change would mean an update of the app.

Comment: You can use a prefilled (you easily create and fill it using a FireFox plugin called SQLiteManager) db OR create it in your DBHelper class. If you must have a predefined set of data, better give a prefilled db.

Comment: I would suggest to use a xml parser. It would be elagant.

Comment: jungleboy, do you have a link to an xml parser example?

Comment: http://androidexample.com/XML_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=69&aaid=94 -> I think I might have found an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends where the data is supposed to come from and how you want to store/edit it.

You can enter it in an XML file inside the app project like you did, and then just access the resources, no need for an XML parser in this case.

Or store it in a separate XML file somewhere on your phone, and use one of Android's built in XML parsers to pull it from there. That way you will only need to change the file and not re-install the app.
You can also store the file on a cloud service (i.e. Dropbox), use any relevant SDK or client service to download it, and then parse it.

BTW, if you're having trouble with the XML parser, consider working with JSON objects and JSON arrays. I personally find them to be a little easier to work with.

Good luck! :)